# Removed some directories being root and Xubuntu won't start

Tags: xorg, xfce, session, restore

I had some problems before doing this where xfce won't start (applications started, but no borders and couldn't type anything on the keyboard) and someone told me to use this command `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/xsessions`

Now not even Xorg will start. I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and use `tty-1` and I tried `apt-get install --reinstall xfce4` but the same problem.

What do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I believe that in 2013 people still run commands with `rm -rf` they find on the internet without trying to work out what they're doing... Perhaps Ubuntu should pop up a big warning the first time a user runs `rm`...

But anyhow... The session file lives in the `xfce4-session` package. Reinstall that and you should be golden.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall xfce4-session
```

And here are a few others:

- For the standard Ubuntu desktop, reinstall `gnome-session`
- For KDE you would want `kde-workspace-data`.
- For Gnome-shell reinstall `gnome-shell`.
- For AwesomeWM, reinstall `awesome`.

There are others but I don't know their xsession names to look them up by.

Comment: I did a --reinstall xfce4, isn't that the same?

Comment: Not at all. `xfce4` is a meta-package that depends on a whole raft of other packages. When you `--reinstall` a meta-package you tend not to actually reinstall anything. I've checked the archive and `xfce4-session` is where this file actually comes from. Reinstalling it will regenerate it.